# Color scheme trasformations

Tags: web, html, color-scheme, color-space

Given a set of colors, say colors on this webpage, and another palette of an equal number of colors, *what would be a good way to map the former to the latter* while:

- preserving contrast between individual colors
- preserving the relative intensity of the colors (not sure how important this would be)

Essentially, this webpage should be rendered in the new color palette while still legible.

*What color space would be appropriate for this task?*

*Can you also point me to any related work?*

**Update**: The mapping can surely be done manually but I intend to automate the mapping for any given set of colors and palette and so I'm looking for an algorithmic approach or rather an understanding of what properties need to be preserved in favor of legibility and beauty.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it is better to transform colours into HSV, and then transform hue (and than back to original encoding). We use brightness (dark elements) and saturation (unselected buttons, etc) as semantic element, so it is better to preserve it.

In such way you maintain also the contrast.

But: normal HSV is not really a true physiological HSV: the most used formula are just set for gamut of RGB, and to give maximum range and being the parameter independent. On reality maximum V depend on H (if one want to compare V between different colours), and other effect.

And These and other visual effects (not in any HSV) will effect the visual result, so you may do it programmatically (e.g. JavaScript which read and override all colours, but this is a topic for other questions), but if you do a website professionally, you must still manually tweak some elements.

Note: last version of CSS, and many CSS preprocessors allow you to use HSV values, and apply programmatically saturation, light and hue changes.